# GWT Bootstrap3 dynamic theme

Tags: gwt, gwtbootstrap3

I'm trying to dynamically change bootstrap themes with GWTBootstrap3. I'm not sure where to start looking, so I haven't tried anything at all. I found an outdated article for the older gwt-boostrap. But all I've found for bootstrap3 is [this info](https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3/wiki/Custom-Theme) which only shows how to attach a theme. I need to be able to switch it based on variables in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my bootstrap include in the gwt.xml to :

```
<inherits name="org.gwtbootstrap3.GwtBootstrap3NoTheme"/>
```

then I included a function I found here on stackoverflow to load the bootstrap I downloaded:

```
public static native void loadCss(String url)/*-{
        var fileref=document.createElement("link");
        fileref.setAttribute("rel","stylesheet");
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/css");
        fileref.setAttribute("href", url);
        $doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
    }-*/;
```

This allows me to decide which theme I want to load. If you want the stock theme, you will have to manually load it as well.